# Extract covariance matrix nonlinear fit

Tags: sas, covariance, nonlinear-functions, sas-jmp, jsl

Using a JSL script, I would like to extract the covariance matrix of a nonlinear model. 
I have a 4PL curve. But when I request:
m["Logistic 4P"]["Parameter Estimates"]["Covariance of Estimates"]["Reference"][""];

It is said that it is an outlinebox and therefore can't be converted into a Data Table, nor a matrix.

However, while right clicking on it, I can convert it in both, so it must be possible using JSL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finaly found it, If it can help someone:

```
m["Logistic 4P"]["Parameter Estimates"]["Covariance of Estimates"]["Reference"][1] << make into data table;
```